# Selenium Java : java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "pages.LoginPage.setUsername(String)" because "this.loginPage" is null

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

Look at this code

**LoginTest.java**

```
public class LoginTest extends BaseTest{
    public LoginPage loginPage;
    @Test
    public void successLogin(){
        loginPage.setUsername("174172****");
        loginPage.setPassword("********");
        WelcomePage welcomePage = loginPage.clickBtn();
        assertTrue(welcomePage.setWelcomeAlert().contains("WELCOME"),
                "Alert text is incorrect");
    }
}
```

**LoginPage.java**

```
public class LoginPage {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private By usernameField = By.id("username");
    private By passwordField = By.id("password");
    private By loginBtn = By.xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Login']");
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username){
        driver.findElement(usernameField).sendKeys(username);
    }
    public void setPassword(String password){
        driver.findElement(passwordField).sendKeys(password);
    }
    public WelcomePage clickBtn(){
        driver.findElement(loginBtn).click();
        return new WelcomePage(driver);
    }
}
```

I started to learn Selenium Java and I tried to make a automation script for Login, but I faced error like this
[error_mssg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81hAn.png)
Anyone can help me to solve this?

i tried to add this code to **LoginTest.java**
`public LoginPage loginPage;`
but I don't know if that's the right code or no

Comment: Did you mean `public LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(myWebDriver);`?

Comment: @Bohemian no, only this code
`public LoginPage loginPage;`

Comment: and got error message
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "pages.LoginPage.setUsername(String)" because "this.loginPage" is null**

Comment: yes, because you haven't initialised `loginPage`. Somewhere, you must execute `myLoginTest.loginPage = new LoginPage(myWebDriver);`